# MVC PayPal intergration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, paypal, code-first

I have my site working so a user can pay via card however now I also need to use PayPal, I can't seem to send the products over from the shopping cart to the paypal controller, each individual product needs to be sent over in the order.

Here is my PayPal controller;

```
namespace T_shirt_Company_v3.Controllers
{
    public class PayPalController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult RedirectFromPaypal()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult CancelFromPaypal()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult NotifyFromPaypal()
        {
            return View();
        }



        public ActionResult ValidateCommand(string RecordId, string CartTotal)
        {



            bool useSandbox = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsSandbox"]);
            var paypal = new PayPal(useSandbox);


            paypal.item_name = RecordId;
            paypal.amount = CartTotal;
            return View(paypal);
        }
    }
}
```

And my View for checkout that I need the details from;

```
@model T_shirt_Company_v3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
}
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToDelete != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", {"id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                        }
                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<center>
    <h3>
        Review your cart:
    </h3>
    <p class="button">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateCommand", "PayPal"))
            {
                <input type="submit" name="btnConfirm" value="Check Out with Paypal" />
            }


        @Html.ActionLink((string)ViewBag.CartStatus, (string)ViewBag.Link, (string)ViewBag.Link2)

        @Html.ActionLink("Continue Shopping ", "Index", "Store")



</p>
<div id="update-message">
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Product Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Price (each)
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in
                Model.CartItems)
    {
        <tr id="row-@item.RecordId">
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Product.Title,
"Details", "Store", new { id = item.ProductId }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Product.Price
            </td>
            <td id="item-count-@item.RecordId">
                @item.Count
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="RemoveLink"
                   data-id="@item.RecordId">
                    Remove
                    from cart
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td>
            Total
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="cart-total">
            @Model.CartTotal
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
```

And the controller;

```
namespace T_shirt_Company_v3.Controllers
{
    public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
    {
        TshirtStoreDB storeDB = new TshirtStoreDB();
        //
        // GET: /ShoppingCart/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

                // Set up the ViewModel
                ShoppingCartViewModel viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
                {
                    CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
                    CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
                };


            if (viewModel.CartItems.Any())
            {
                ViewBag.CartStatus = "Proceed to checkout or ";
                ViewBag.Link = "AddressAndPayment";
                ViewBag.Link2 = "Checkout";

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.CartStatus = "Cart is empty please ";
                ViewBag.Link = "Index";
                ViewBag.Link2 = "Store";
            }

            // Return the view
            return View(viewModel);
        }


        //
        // GET: /Store/AddToCart/5(ID)
        public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
        {
            // Retrieve the Product from the database
            var addedProduct = storeDB.Products
                .Single(product => product.ProductId == id);

            // Add it to the shopping cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

            // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        //
        // AJAX: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5(ID)
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
        {
            // Remove the item from the cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            // Get the name of the product to display confirmation
            string productName = storeDB.Carts
                .Single(item => item.RecordId == id).Product.Title;

            // Removes item from cart
            int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);

            // Display the confirmation message saying removed from cart
            var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = Server.HtmlEncode(productName) +
                    " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id
            };
            return Json(results);
        }
        //
        // GET: /ShoppingCart/CartSummary
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult CartSummary()
        {
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

            ViewData["CartCount"] = cart.GetCount();
            return PartialView("CartSummary");
        }


        //test close connection when done
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            storeDB.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I read your code correctly, you're only rendering the data, you're not sending it (at all).

- your `form` only has a `button` (it's the only "data" sent)
- you need to include the data you rendered as `form` fields (`<input />`)

Hth.

Answer (score 0):

As PayPal Api is dependent on a set of operations that must be understood before used, developers should focus on understanding the operations summary, before using the Api, also a sandbox is available for testing before officially using the Api.

You should know how to use the RESTful endpoint structure of PayPal.

You can check the PayPal Api documentation for details on how to integrate your web application with PayPal using [REST API Reference.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/)